# A paper seems to have completely disappeared from editor's hands

Tags: journals, career

I have submitted a paper to a journal on June 2017. The corresponding author is my coauthor. The first response of the editor was after a year, June 2018:

> Your paper has been sent, consecutively, to four referees.
>   Of the preceding three, one declined to review it and two 
>   never responded to the invitation or to multiple reminders.
>   The fourth one accepted; a report is expected in September [2018].

Since then, the editor disappeared. No notice at all, neither in the positive, nor in the negative. Obviously we tried to contact him again multiple times (approximately every two-three months) through the journal's platform. No response at all. We sent countless emails to the editor, either via the platform or through his personal email (my coauthor knows him in person). No response at all. We tried to contact the chief editor. No response at all.

In a few days, it will be exactly two years since the submission: this is an incredible amount of time, especially since we absolutely don't know what is the motivation for this delay.

What shall we do?

[I'm not posting this on academia, since this is a paper in Mathematics; but feel free to migrate the discussion elsewhere if you feel like so]

Unfortunately I am unable to comment as I lack sufficient reputation.

1. Yes, "consecutively" means exactly that 3 people in a row refused to referee the paper; the fourth accepted and then disappeared since June 2018.
2. The editor-in-chief should be aware of what's going on, more so because we wrote him an email two weeks ago or so. No answer.
3. The journal is a pretty good and reputable one. At least until I spread this voice.
4. My coauthor has nothing against me if I reveal the name of the journal: it's JoA https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-algebra

Comment: better to migrate this, I think.

Comment: And yet I believe that the right answer comes from a mathematician: the situation shows some of the typical idiosyncrasies of mathematics' publishing world. Plus, withdrawing papers that are not evaluated quickly is much less common a practice in mathematics (this would be a viable choice elsewhere, I guess; but I don't want to do it).

Comment: What choice do you have? If the editors won't even reply to emails... Is this a reputable journal?

Comment: btw do any known math journals use 4 referees? I think Annals uses only 3, and they are not a bad journal.

Comment: @schematic_boi I think the word "consecutively" is used here to mean that the paper was sent to one referee at a time, until a satisfactory referee could be found.

Comment: The journal should have an editor-in-chief. If the journal is well-organized the editor-in-chief should be aware of what's going on.

Comment: I would just file all the correspondence, including the sent but unanswered messages, send one more formal message telling the editors that you withdraw the paper, add the journal to my black list, and submit the paper elsewhere. If someone sees some legal or ethical flaw with this idea, please comment, but it is what my common sense dictates.

Comment: You can send a message to the publisher. This might help.Of courde you need to figure out whom exactly to send a message to

Comment: I have serious doubts about the professionalism of such a journal. Can you tell us more precise how did you establish that the journal is "pretty good and reputable"?

Comment: You'd be able to comment on your own question if you log in with the same account you originally used to ask the question.  However, it appears that you have made a second account with the same name, which thus doesn't have comment privileges.  You might want to [merge them](https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @fedja it’s interesting that you mention adding this journal to your black list, as if it’s the most normal thing in the world that every working mathematician has a black list of journals. I do see an ethical flaw here - not with you or your suggestion, but there is definitely a flaw with the mindset of (essentially) all of us that it’s so normal and common for a journal to behave this way that there is nothing to see here or get outraged about, just add the journal to your black list and move on with your life. Why should we put up with this sort of abuse?

Comment: @DanRomik: When you talk of abuse, you are implicitly siding with the OP; there is an old principle of law, though, called ["audiatur et altera pars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audi_alteram_partem). How can we know that the OP's story faithfully reflects the deeds? What if the corresponding author is lying to the OP in order to cover some misdeed of his? What if the OP only tells half of the story - the half that is convenient to him? What if this post is an experiment in sociology to see how we react? Why do you rush to believe without proof, only assuming good faith?

Comment: _Volerem multum audire altera partem_, believe me.

Comment: @GeorgeC.Modoi I see that my edit to the opening post was rejected; maybe it is not a good idea to spread the name of the journal so openly? (my coauthor agrees that we should speak out loud and clear; but as Dan Romik pointed out this is a sick sad world)

Comment: @DanRomik Life is short, world is imperfect, and getting outraged on every occasion one can justly  get outraged with will either bring you to the mental asylum or make you a professional assassin. Blacklisting is enough in most cases as far as people and other entities are concerned. As to "listening to the other side", all I say starts with "If the situation/problem is, indeed, like that, then" by default. We are just used  to the idea that when one talks about math, we are to discuss the question as posed (though sometimes it turns out that the poster has a different setup in mind),

Comment: @caulacau: I was one of those who rejected that edit attempt; the reason is that you attempted to perform it under another username than the one used to ask the question, and this would only confuse us. Feel free to edit your question now with the same name used when asking it, you won't need anybody's approval. And no, the MO community believes in freedom of speech, we do not censor anything here. In fact, since some commenters expressed doubt regarding the quality of the journal, I suggest that you publish its name in full, not just with ellipses (which would be more akin to teasing).

Comment: @GeorgeC.Modoi it's Journal of Algebra. https://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-algebra [at]everybody else: I'm one step far from emailing all the people I know about what happened. When you're a young postdoc, every published paper weighs a lot, and crap like this is what makes other candidates appear better (well, if they are not in the same situation...).

Comment: Elsevier seems to have chat portal, and you can contact the through that portal to know what is happening. I am aware that they help a lot to sort the issues. Also they can provide information of what is happening with your paper.

Comment: Now this is a good advice.

Comment: Does twitter have any leverage in such (unacceptable, unfair, unprofessional) circumstances?

Comment: @caulacau Are you positive that you didn’t make several accounts on the journal’s platform? 

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious, but there are other means of communication besides email. You could try to phone the editor (or the editor-in-chief) to inquire whether your emails have not been lost due to a technical problem, or mail them a letter (I mean, printed on paper: amazingly, this still exists), which, because it is more unusual, might get more attention (and is less likely to get lost en route or buried in mountains of spam).

Comment: Have you tried to contact the editor and the editor-in-chief by phone? Nowadays phones are only used to surf the net and take pictures, but back in the old days they were invented for conversations. (I just realize Gro-Tsen had similar ideas 14 minutes earlier).

Comment: Even if I'm younger than most of you guys, I've seen and used _actual phone boots_, those with coins.

Comment: caulacau don't pay attention to irony. You are right, this looks very strange. I would follow the advice of GabS and if this would not help then do what fedja says. Maybe a letter by the usual mail would be better for this, I don't know.

Comment: By the way, there is another possibility that no one remembered. You can send to some of us (I can help for example) the necessary information and we'll send letters to the editors. In Russia that would be normal, I think, in Europe this is the same.

Comment: @caulacau A few comments: 1. Journal of Algebra is the standard output for good papers in algebra, it would be hard to blacklist it. 2. I had very similar experience recently with another good journal in algebra, you cannot stop submitting papers to so many journals. 3. In the case of that journal I was told the system was changed recently, so it shouldn't happen again. 4. If you know one of the editors  of the journal well, then you can ask for their help.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some additional things to consider:

1. Sometimes email addresses are blocked, for one reason or another.  One of my coauthors had his institution block all hotmail addresses, which led to some trouble in our communications.  In your post you mention "countless" emails; this can cause certain servers to start blocking emails.  Conversely, **their emails to you might be blocked**.  In your correspondence you can mention that you haven't heard anything, and perhaps give them your phone number.
2. Sometimes people are away from computers for multiple weeks.  Then it takes a while to contact the referee.  My personal rule of thumb is to contact an editor and if I receive no reply then I follow up a week later.  I repeat this one more time.  After 3 emails (and 3 weeks of waiting), I believe it is then time to contact the editor-in-chief.  During this process you might try to use alternate email addresses which haven't been potentially blocked.  You do not want to pester an editor with "countless" emails.
3. Some of the issues above can be avoided if the journal in question has its own way to contact editors, which it appears you already tried to use.
4. Nobody should wait multiple months between trying to contact an editor, if they are receiving no responses.  That is unreasonably long.  This noncommunication issue should have been dealt with near the date the editor gave for the report to be done.

Given the time-frame, if you can't get a response from the editor-in-chief through the methods people gave in the comments, I would send one final (kindly worded!) email saying that if you don't hear from them within two weeks, then your paper should be considered as withdrawn.

Comment: I don't like the withdrawn option for two reasons: 1. the author is punished in this option much more than the journal; 2. the system is supposed to serve everyone, so if something is broken it is very important to fix it (this is particularly true for the Journal of Algebra which is very important to the community). However, I am not sure I have a good solution, except making this public which might not be the best thing to do for a young mathematician.

Comment: I don't support public shaming, but I agree that we (as a community) should have the discussion of what behaviors are inappropriate, and discuss ways to handle them--perhaps expanding the AMS statement?  To give a personal example: A referee report was supposed to occur at 6 months.  At 9 months I followed up, asking where we were.  The editor said he was giving the referee another 3 months (even though the referee had stopped responding to emails).  At 12 months I followed up again, and the editor finally decided to get a new referee, giving them another 7 months to write the report!

Comment: The AMS statement I refer to is: http://www.ams.org/about-us/governance/policy-statements/sec-ethics  I like how they make clear that it is the duty of the editors to get the paper refereed in a timely manner.  This could perhaps be expanded a bit to clarify what timely does and does not mean.

Comment: The problem with time expectations from the editors and the referees is that they are not realistic. The whole system is broken, editors struggle to find referees, referees struggle to find time, and authors don't help much as many do not put enough effort to make their papers accessible (often they are not even correct). The only long time solution I can think of is paying the referees (and editors). Then you can demand that the work should be done on time and with high quality.